# Detect the number of cores on windows

Tags: windows, r, multicore

If I am running R on linux or on a mac, I can detect the number of available cores using `multicore:::detectCores()`.  However, there's no windows version of the multicore functions, so I can't use this technique on windows.

How can I programmatically detect the number of cores on a windows machine, from within R?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The parallel package now has a function to detect the number of cores: `parallel:::detectCores()`.

Comment: Seems to be the best way. `detectCores()` is platform-independent and returns a number, whereas `Sys.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")` returns a string.

Comment: Yes but it's easy enough to convert to an integer. And I don't need to install a new package.

Answer (score 13):

This [thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Programmaticly-finding-number-of-processors-by-R-code-td2953437.html) has a number of suggestions, including:

```
Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')
```

Note also the posting in that thread by Prof. Ripley which talks to the difficulties of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually need to distinguish between actual cores, chips, and logical processors, the API to call is [GetLogicalProcessInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) if just want to know how many logical processors on a machine (with no differentiation for hyperthreading.).

How you call this from "R" is beyond me. But I'd guess R has a facility for invoking code from native Windows DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

[GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you a structure that has the number of "processors", which corresponds to the total number of cores.

In theory, it will be the same value as the environment variable recommended in another answer, but the user can tamper with (or delete) the environment variable.  That can be a bug or a feature depending on your intent.

Comment: GetSystemInfo will only return the logical number of processors, not cores.  So if you have hyperthreading on your CPU, you'll likely get 2x the number of actual cores.

Comment: @selbie: If you have two four-core processors, you get 8, not 2, which is why I claimed it's the number of cores.  I'd never seen GetLocicalProcessInformation before.  That's clearly a better way to go.  Note, I've never seen a case where the NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable defaults to something different than what GetSystemInfo defaults to.  I have, however, seen people muck with NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, resulting in badly tuned applications.  So I'd strongly recommend not using the environment variable.