# Detect the Number of Cores Available on a Machine using R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, parallel-foreach

Does `detectCores()` return the number of physical processors or the number of available processors at that time?

```
detectCores {parallel}
Attempt to detect the number of CPU cores on the current host.
```

I have given some dedicated cores to another script also, but I am not sure if `detectCores()` will only use available resources or if it will register with all cores.

```
 cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
  registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores())
```

Alternatively, is `getDoParWorkers()` the right function to get the available number of cores? Any help? I went through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954991/whether-to-use-the-detectcores-function-in-r-to-specify-the-number-of-cores-for) but 
didnt find the right way of detecting it.

Comment: It returns the number of physical cores and doesn't take into account current system load. If you assigned a certain number of cores for some other task perhaps you could subtract that number away when you call `registerDoParallel`.

Comment: This actually depends on the operating system, it may return the number of logical CPUs - see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/detectCores.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect the number of cores on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389334/detect-the-number-of-cores-on-windows)